# Excel - search values in one column, but copy values to the left of result(s)

Tags: excel, csv, search, find

I have tried the excel functions (that I am familiar with) and have not been able to find a way to do this. I would like to search column Y for "Foo", and wherever I get a result, I want to copy the contents to the left (column X) of each cell containing "Foo". Is this something I would have to do via csv conversion?

i.e. below, I would like to copy only ab & sa into a new spread, while maintaining them as separate cells (order is not important)

```
X     Y
ab    Foo
bd    Bar
se    Bar
sa    Foo
ge    Bar
```

Comment: Are you looking for a formula or vba?  A formula will be an array type and may be slow if the data set is large.

Comment: @ScottCraner either, the file type is not too large, but I was not able to come up with a formula on my own that would work (as far as my previous usage of excel would permit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula would be something like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(X:X,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($Y$1:$Y$5)/($Y$1:$Y$5="Foo"),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Put it in the first cell and copy down till you return blanks.

[image]